# Infinite Sum of 1/Polynomial

Tags: sequences-and-series, power-series

I'm trying to solve this equation:

$$\sum_{k = 0}^{\infty}\dfrac{1}{(k+1)(k+3)}$$

Original image at https://i.stack.imgur.com/2WINT.png

I attempted to find the sums of

$\sum_0^∞\frac{1}{k+1}$ and $\sum_0^∞\frac{1}{k+3}$ and then attempt to multiply, but then I realized neither converges, due to the denominator power being equal to 1.

How do I do this?

Comment: If you're implying that $\sum a_n \sum b_n = \sum a_n b_n$, note that this is wrong.

Comment: Even if $\sum\frac{1}{k+1}$ and $\sum\frac{1}{k+3}$ converged, their product would *not* be equal to $\sum\frac{1}{(k+1)(k+3)}$. Have a look at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_product

Answer (score 2):

Hint: partial fractions, telescoping series...

Comment: I'm sorry @Robert, but I don't think I know telescoping series. I have an exam tomorrow in 13 hours, so if you could explain in further detail I would truly appreciate it.

Comment: Telescoping is where each term after the next cancels out when you add/subtract 2 series

Comment: @MathNoob, I've tried expanding the denominator, and I get:

$\sum_0^∞ \frac{1}{k^2 + 4k + 3}$ but don't see what to do next.

Comment: Instead of multiplication, use partial fractions first

Comment: @user2793230: Further hint: Work out what $\frac1{k+1}-\frac1{k+3}$ is.

Answer (score 1):

Applying partial fractions, we find $$\frac{1}{(k+1)(k+3)}=\frac{\frac{1}{2}}{k+1}-\frac{\frac{1}{2}}{k+3}$$

Hence we have

\begin{align}\sum\limits_{k=0}^\infty\frac{1}{(k+1)(k+3)}&=\frac{1}{2}\sum\limits_{k=0}^\infty\left(\frac{1}{k+1}-\frac{1}{k+3}\right)
\\&=\frac{1}{2}\left[\frac{1}{1}+\frac{1}{2}+\sum\limits_{k=0}^\infty\left(\frac{1}{k+3}-\frac{1}{k+3}\right)\right]
\\&=\frac{1}{2}\left[\frac{1}{1}+\frac{1}{2}\right]
\\&=\frac{3}{4}\end{align}

Where in the antepenultimate step we have just changed the index of the first part of the summation.

Comment: Okay, and @Peter, may I ask how you got the 1/2 on the denominator?

Comment: Kudos for use of the word "antepenultimate."  But you should probably put parentheses around the two terms being summed in it and the preantepenultimate line.

Comment: @BarryCipra LOL, yes points for antepenultimate.

Comment: @BarryCipra Thanks

Comment: @Peter Because I'm attempting to determine the coefficients for the two partial fraction terms as follows:

$\frac{A}{k+1}-\frac{B}{k-3}$

$A(k+3)-B(k+1)=1$

$Ak+3A-Bk-B=1$

$Ak-Bk=0k$

$A-B=0$

$3A-B=1$

$B=-\frac{1}{4}$

Comment: @user2793230 Yeah, the $\frac{1}{2}$ term comes from the partial fraction decomposition, which you can read about [here](http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/Alg/PartialFractions.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Further hint: What is $\frac{1}{k+1} - \frac{1}{k+3}$ with a common denominator?

How does that result relate to $\frac{1}{(k+1)(k+3)}$?

What happens to each term because you're subtracting?

Comment: Well, separating the sum into $frac\{1}{k+1}$ - $frac\{1}{k+3}$, I get a sequence like this:

$\frac{1}{1}-\frac{1}\{3}$+$\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{4}$

And so forth. Does this come into some sort of a pattern?

Comment: @user2793230 Yes. If you write out more terms, you'll notice -1/3 and +1/3 cancel, -1/4 and +1/4 cancel, etc.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**:  Have you seen this example?

$$\begin{align}
\sum_{k=1}^\infty{1\over k(k+1)}&=\sum_{k=1}^\infty\left({1\over k}-{1\over k+1} \right)\\
&=\left({1\over1}-{1\over2}\right)+\left({1\over2}-{1\over3}\right)+\left({1\over3}-{1\over4}\right)+\cdots\\
&=1-\left({1\over2}-{1\over2}\right)-\left({1\over3}-{1\over3}\right)-\cdots
\end{align}$$

Your series is similar (albeit a bit more complicated).