# Are there applications of partial fraction decomposition ( of a rational function) outside integration problems?

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, soft-question, partial-fractions

I've been recently acquainted with a well known  technique called " partial fraction decomposition" which allows, for example to express $\frac {x} {x^2-1}$ as $\frac {1}{2(x+1)} + \frac {1} {2(x-1)}$.

If I am correct, this technique is ordinarily used in calculus to integrate rational functions ( quotients of polynomials).

My question is simply whether there is some basic application of this technique outside integration problems, and even outside Calculus.

Is it possible to exhibit a possible use of PFD in algebra proper, and particularly, it would be nice to see a way it can be used in the ***discussion of a rational function.***

Here I am not interested essentially in sophisticated applications, but rather in basic ones ( at "Algebra $2$" level, say).

Any reference is also welcome.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: For other examples, telescoping sums/series ([1](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1072753/infinite-sum-of-1-polynomial)), Taylor expansions ([2](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3759138/binomial-expansion-of-frac24x-4x3)).

Comment: This can be used to prove general theorems about difference equations/recurrence relations (using @dxiv's idea of Taylor expansions - or binomial expansions): a good method for seeing what is going on when there are multiple roots of the characteristic equation.

Comment: Finding the Egyptian fraction expansion of a fraction may use some PFD.

Comment: In signal processing for example, you often use partial fraction decomposition in the computation of inverse Laplace transforms. Even though, it's technically kind of related to integration, I think they are quite relevant to mention here :p

Comment: Here is an application of partial fraction expansion, in the field of euclidean geometry. If $P\in\mathbb{C}[X]$ has degree $n\geqslant 2$, then the roots of $P'$ (the dérivative of $P$) belong to the convex hull of the set of roots of $P$. This result is known as Luca's theorem. See here : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gauss%E2%80%93Lucas_theorem

Comment: Another application : knowing the partial fraction expansion of $R$ enables to compute easily the successive derivatives of $R$.